# limit number of editors windows in STS (eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, editor

I know how to limit the number of editor windows in IntelliJ but I can't find the setting in STS (Eclipse).

Please advise as I want to set it to 1 editor window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To limit the number of opened editor windows, go to *Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors*. Select *Close editors automatically* and set the value of *Number of opened editors before closing* to 1, as shown below:

[image: Limit number of editor windows]

Comment: Thanks - I knew there was a way to do it - I had done it before - but I've slept since then :)